# How to create base class with type in python that overrides a variable?

Tags: python

Assume this example:

```
class A(object):
    def add(self, number):
        self.n += number

 B = type("B", (A,), {"n":3})
 b = B()
 b.add(5)
 b.n
```

This code works for me and returns a b.n = 8 or b.n=3 after object creation, but if the class A is changed to

```
class A(object):
    def__init__(self):
        self.n = 0
    def add(self, number):
        self.n += number
 B = type("B", (A,), {"n":3})
 b = B()
 b.add(5)
 b.n
```

In this case the b.n is only 5, after object creation it seems that the n is taken from the base class and not from the newly created class. Is there a way to have the n object overwritten at creation time of object B ?

Answer (score 3):

The dictionary passed as third argument to `type` are the *class* members. That is, your `type` invocation is equivalent to:

```
class B(A):
    n = 3
```

`A.__init__` is inherited, and it adds an instance variable. Instance variables shadow class variables, so `b.n` starts out as 0 (while `B.n` is indeed 3).

Note that the inheritance is irrelevant, the code below shows the same behavior:

```
class B(object):
    n = 3

    def __init__(self):
        self.n = 0

    def add(self, number):
        self.n += number
```

Answer (score 0):

@delnan gives an explanation of *why* this is happening.

The following shows *how* you can do what you're trying to do:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.n = 0
    def add(self, number):
        self.n += number

def create_B(initial_n):
  class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
      self.n = initial_n
  return B

B = create_B(3)
b = B()
b.add(5)
print b.n
```